# Access to s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to give different access to different buckets in s3? In detail, I have 10 different buckets in s3 and each of those bucket related to different people. So I want to give them access only to their particular bucket(by sharing a URL or something like that)
Is this possible?

Comment: How do you want these people to access Amazon S3 — will they be directly uploading/downloading files, or will they be interacting with an application? Are these users internal to your company (eg other IT staff), or are they external users? How will they authenticate themselves (so the system knows who they are)?

Comment: They are external users. And they have separate buckets in a single s3 account. The thought is they need to download all their (their only) files from s3. So is this possible to provide access only to their particular bucket? Is it possible for them to directly download from s3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to assign access is:

- Permanent credentials (eg associate with an **IAM User**) are only provided to **internal IT staff** who are managing or using the AWS services.
- End users of a **web application** should be **authenticated** by the application (eg using Amazon Cognito, LDAP, AD, Google). The application will then be responsible for generating **Pre-Signed URLs** for uploading and downloading files.
- For **mobile applications**, it is quite common to **create temporary credentials using the Security Token Service**, which allows the mobile app to **directly make AWS API calls**. The credentials can be given limited permissions, such as only being able to access one S3 bucket.

So, it really comes down to 'how' the users will be accessing the bucket. If they are doing it directly, then provide temporary credentials via STS. If they are doing it via an application, then the application will be responsible for providing individual access to upload/download.

By the way, it's not necessarily a good idea to give a different bucket to every user, because there is a limit on the number of buckets you can create. Instead, you could give access to separate paths **within the same bucket**. Proper use of permissions will ensure they cannot see/impact other users' data.

For how this works with IAM Users, see: [Variables in AWS Access Control Policies | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/variables-in-aws-access-control-policies/)